# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function redirect() PHP logout session

Tags: php, session, undefined, fatal-error

I have problem when I logout in an admin panel with the logout page session. It shows the following error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function redirect() in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\CMS\admin\logout.php:7 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown
>   in C:\xampp\htdocs\CMS\admin\logout.php on line 7

Instead, it should show the login page. My code:

```
<?php include("includes/header.php");?>

<?php
$session->logout();
redirect("login.php");
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `redirect` function doesn't exist in PHP. You want to use `header`:

```
header("Location: login.php");
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Comment: this solution work but i have problem i create function for location  mentioned below

Comment: @Junaid what do you mean?

Comment: function redirect($location){

    header("Location:{$location}"); when i call this function with session than it cannot work.

Comment: @Junaid Try `header("Location: $location"); `. What is the value of `$location`

Comment: $location value = "index.php"; thanks for your help. I write redirect("login.php"); like these die( redirect("login.php"); and it works.